# Create Path from PointF array

Tags: android

I have a `PointF[]` filled with coordinates of a line. Can I use this to create a `Path` object?
My ultimate goal is to have two such `Path`. Then create `Region` using the `Path` objects and check whether they intersect.

```
region1.op(region2, Op.INTERSECT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this by foot:

```
PointF[] input = ...;
path = new Path();
path.moveTo(input[0].x, input[0].y);
for(int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    path.lineTo(input[i].x, input[i].y);
}
```